# Custom CursorAdapter Design

Tags: java, android

Here's the code which I use for my Android custom cursor adapter which I use to bind data to my list view.

```
public class MessageAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
   private Cursor mCursor;
   private Context mContext;
   private final LayoutInflater mInflater;


    public MessageAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        TextView mobileNo=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mobileNolistitem);
        mobileNo.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TextMeDBAdapter.KEY_MOBILENO)));

        TextView frequency=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.frequencylistitem);
        frequency.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TextMeDBAdapter.KEY_FREQUENCY)));

        TextView rowid=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rowidlistitem);
        rowid.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TextMeDBAdapter.KEY_ID)));

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.message_list_item,parent,false); 
        return view;
    }

}
```

I know that there's another efficient way to do this which reuses the list item instantiated.  Can someone tell me how?

Comment: I'm still getting started on Android apps. What list item are you refering to?

Comment: I'm referring to the list items in the list.See this video by Romain guy on making a good and efficient list view http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA , although it's pretty long.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is exactly* the way you should be using your `CursorAdapter`. I'm sure you're referring to "recycling" the Views as talked about when overriding the `getView()` method of a `BaseAdapter`.

In the case of the `CursorAdapter`, all of that is taken care of for you so that just implementing `newView()` and `bindView()` fully takes advantage of the View recycling you're asking about.

Here is the code for `CursorAdapter.getView()`:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (!mDataValid) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
    }
    if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
    }
    View v;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v = newView(mContext, mCursor, parent);
    } else {
        v = convertView;
    }
    bindView(v, mContext, mCursor);
    return v;
}
```

So you see, the method attempts to recycle the View that was passed in by checking `convertView == null`. If successful, it uses that View and simply calls `bindView()` to set it up appropriately. If `convertView` is null, it calls `newView()` to create the View, followed by `bindView()` to set it up. This is one of the rare instances on SE that I can say "You're doing it right!"

- But to nitpick, there's really no reason to maintain a reference to your Context in `mContext` - You're not using it anywhere and maintaining references to Contexts can lead to memory leaks, and ultimately the end of the world.

Comment: One more thing You should definitely use - save pointers to all views with a ViewHolder, in order not to findViewById every time.

Answer (score 8):

It would be even easier to use a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, but the exact same principal applies for `CursorAdapter`. You can cache the calls to `findViewById()` on the view and even `getColumnIndex` on the cursor by storing the data in the views tag. Using this stopped by `ListView` rendering slowly.

The `ViewHolder` pattern is borrowed from Efficient Adapter API demo [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html).

```java
public static class CustomSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    /* constructor(); */

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        if (holder == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            holder.column1 = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("column1");
            holder.column2 = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("column2");
            view.setTag(holder);
        }

        holder.textView1.setText(cursor.getString(holder.column1));
        holder.textView2.setText(cursor.getString(holder.column2));
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView1;
        TextView textView2;
        int column1; 
        int column2;
    }
}
```

Comment: THe ViewHolder is the concept to go with, it costs a little bit of ram, but speeds up the binding of the view. @Tom Curran: Though I don't understand why you would get and keep the column index for every view, you should get it in the constructor and put in in two final fields!